# Just the pictures answers the questions. A picture is worth a thousand words

Tags: discussion

In my answer was deleted. I think because of a misunderstanding of how stackexchange works and a misinterpretation of the rules.  Letting perfect get in the way of the good.

[How do astronauts brave a 19 hour trip like in the SpaceX Demo-2 launch?](https://space.stackexchange.com/questions/44351/how-do-astronauts-brave-a-19-hour-trip-like-in-the-spacex-demo-2-launch/44393#44393)

I notice when I put in a link to a movie that a picture was was inserted. A single picture answers part of the posters question. No need for a lot of words.

I noticed the image was grabbed from the video and saved here: 
https://i.ytimg.com/vi/6vVle67Tfjc/sddefault.jpg

Who owns ytimag.com?
https://www.whois.com/whois/ytimg.com

Looks like Google. Who placed the image on Google? It would seem to me that stackexchange did it.  If stackexchange thinks google is good enough a place to store something, who I'm I to complain.

I know the rule about not relying on links. I thought about this before posting.  I figured the dinning picture provided enough information to answer the question with out the more detailed picture. I believe a picture is worth a thousand words.  The pictures in themselves answered the question.

By deleting this post:
-- you deprive the poster of a significant amount of information
-- even if you do not like the link to the food.  The picture of the capsule answers part of the question. A picture offers more proof then words.

You probably cannot see the original.
[image]

PS.  I figured this would get down voted too. Real friendly.

Comment: FYI - Downvotes on meta are not a rude button. It is a way for users to indicate what they desire site policy to be by disagreement.

Comment: When I start participating on a new site I try to think of it as if I'm visiting a new country with different customs and practices. When I get *unexpected results* like this (something I thought was good getting rejected or criticized) I just chalk it up as a learning experience and a way to find out how things are done differently in different sites. The answer posted so far does a great job of outlining aspects of this site's approach to answering questions and it may differ from your experience in other sites, but that's what site-to-site "travel" is like.

Comment: Coming to meta to request more information is *exactly the right thing to do*, and as pointed out above down votes in meta mean something different than they do on a main site. Some meta posts in high volume sites get tens *or even hundreds* of down votes! It just means that a lot of people disagree with the sentiment, and it's just a way of finding out how others tend to feel about a specific point. It does not mean that it's not a good question or that you shouldn't have asked it. I'll still down vote here for the same reason, but as you see I took the time to acknowledge your question!

Answer (score 7):

Answers that rely heavily on images and videos are frowned upon here. There are a couple reasons for this:

1. For images specifically, an answer is usually clearer if there is an explanation. Not everyone has the context to understand what a picture shows.
2. For images and video, it is bad for accessibility to rely on the images and videos because someone with a poor internet connection or with visual disabilities may not be able to access the images.
3. For videos specifically, they are links to an external site, and they can go down. It is universal Stack Exchange philosophy that the point of this site is to gather all necessary information here, so that it is not lost due to link rot.

Comment: And, with all things that are behind a link: links can break. Thus most of the information must be in the post itself if as much as possible.

Answer (score 2):

This answer has problems above and beyond being link-only.

Reviewing the sub-questions asked:

> - Are the astronauts going to remain immobile through the duration of    flight?
> - How do astronauts manage trips like this (in terms of things such as    feeding themselves and attending to nature's call)?
> - Are there things which are done differently in this vehicle?

Nothing in what you posted addresses these questions.

*A stack exchange answer must address the question that is asked.*